# Sending Excel attachment & Image in the Body in same SSRS email

Tags: image, reporting-services, ssrs-2012, body-parser, attached-properties

I'm trying to send a report using SSRS which include an image in the email body and the report is excel attached.

[image]

I want to put an image in the blue box( Body of the Email), and the report generate by ssrs in attached as excel

I tried to put a text in comment field, but no image allowed
[image]